# Formatting the year in highcharts

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts, django-templates

I'm pulling data from django templates for my highcharts series. I have Year as the X-axis and Rating as the Y-axis, however it displays the year as a decimal,such as the year "1998" is displayed as "1,998". I want the year to be displayed normally without the comma.

Here is my code for the axis and series:

```
xAxis: {
    title: {
        type: 'datetime',
        text: 'Year',
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Rating'
    }
},
series: [{
    data: [
    {% for item in graph_data %}
    {
        name: '{{item}}',
        x: {{item.year}},
        y: {{item.rating}}
    },
    {% endfor %}
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used an array of date time x and y for data points in the series, you need to use Date.UTC() to convert the time to universal time first. And the `type` property isn't inside the `title` property.

So try this

```
xAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Year',
    }
    type: 'datetime'
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Rating'
    }
},
series: [{
    data: [
    {% for item in graph_data %}
    {
        name: '{{item}}',
        x: Date.UTC({{item.year}}, month, date),
        y: {{item.rating}}
    },
    {% endfor %}
    ]
}]
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6abdq/1/

Comment: It's actually x: Date.UTC({{item.year}},0,0), since the {{item.year}} calls a variable passed on from the django view. But thanks, what threw me off was type: datetime being misplaced within the title bracket.

Comment: @user2027556 Thank you for your correction. Didn't pay much attention to that part. If the month and date is trivial, it is actually x:Date.UTC({{item.year}},0,1) since date should be an integer between 1 and 31

Answer (score 0):

You can use label [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) and return value, inluding [dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29)

Comment: label formatter works pretty well. And it seems easier to use. Can you tell me which way is better in general, or it depends on case?

Comment: Generally formatter seems to be more "user friedly" in the code and more more transparent for user, but it is my opinion.